# User input text box size not changing on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Website: https://schallertenterprises.com/cuttertravelcalculator/

I have these 3 user input text boxes created with formidable forms. I have set the width of them to be a certain size using the formidable forms plugin, but when on mobile, that size adjustment does not apply. It seems to default to the width of the page size when on mobile. Anyone know if this is fixable?

Answer (score 0):

Add this **CSS** in your plugin or theme style.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
 .frm_form_fields .frm_fields_container > .frm_form_field {
        grid-column: 1 / span 3 !important;
    }
}
```